# Скрипт javascript "оставьте заявку до **" как сделать?

Tags: php, javascript, веб-программирование

Всем привет. Сейчас начал изучать PHP, но здесь вроде JavaScript.
Как сделать скрипт, чтобы каждый день было текущее число.

> Оставьте заявку до 20.08 (включительно) и получите скидку 25%

21 числа будет написано 21.08 и т.д

Comment: да тут на пхп можно `echo Date('dd.mm')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для получения даты можно использовать конструкцию в JS:

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //Январь не может быть нулем
if(dd<10) {
    dd = '0'+dd
 } 

if(mm<10) {
    mm = '0'+mm
} 
var today = dd+'.'+mm;
```

Дальше привести ее к формату, который вы желаете, и в html оставить элемент "span" с каким-нибудь Id, после чего найти этот элемент и вставить в него текст:

```
document.getElementById("myspan").innerHTML=today;
```

Comment: Вроде объяснили лаконично. Но я ничего не понял. 
1. Делаю скрипт `<script> var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //Январь не может быть нулем
var today = dd+'.'+mm;</script>`
2. Потом `<p><span id="myspan"></span></p>`

Как прописать правильно, делаю я это в форме? Я плохо знаю синтаксис. 
Спасибо за ответы)

Comment: Вы правильно указали с точки зрения синтаксиса, возможно у вас возникла ошибка из-за text.Content, если вы его использовали, так как он не везде работает, остальное должно работать, если нет, то посмотрите, какая ошибка у вас в консоли браузера

Comment: Выводит 15.8, вместо 15.08, можно как то дату изменить?

Comment: @ДаниилДаниил Добавил проверку если месяц или день меньше 10

Comment: Огромное спасибо. В плане логики всё элементарно, как всегда у меня проблемы с синтаксисом. Плюсик не могу поставить, пока что баллов не хватает, сделаю когда будет возможность)

Comment: @ДаниилДаниил Всегда пожалуйста, но было бы неплохо, если бы в таком случае отметили бы ответ как правильный, чтобы не смущать остальных участников сообщества

Comment: Блин, вроде написан вами верно, но не работает, все равно 8.

Comment: @ДаниилДаниил исправил, была ошибка в присвоении значения переменной today до того, как были обработаны день и месяц

Comment: Заработало, спасибо!)